# Procedure or function 'sp_InsertExams' expects parameter '@NegativeMarking', which was not supplied

Tags: c#

I am getting error on stored procedure : 
Procedure or function 'sp_InsertExams' expects parameter '@NegativeMarking', which was not supplied. I have passed the negativemarking  parameter but it's not working.....can any one help me to solve this problem.

stored procedure:

```
USE [WebBasedExamBackUp]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_InsertExams]    Script Date: 09/01/2015 17:57:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_InsertExams](@ExamName varchar(50),@Description varchar(1000),
                                @NoOfQues int,@NegativeMarking varchar(100),
                                @ExamTypeId int,@Out varchar(150) output)  
as
begin  
if not exists(select ExamId from tbl_Exams where ExamName=@ExamName)  
begin  
declare @status varchar(50)
declare @date datetime
set @date=(select convert(datetime,(select getdate()),103))
insert into tbl_Exams
(ExamName,[Description],DOR,NoOfQuestions,NegativeMarking,ExamTypeId)
values
(@ExamName,@Description,@date,@NoOfQues,@NegativeMarking,@ExamTypeId)
set @out='Exam Name Submitted Successfully.'  
end  
else
begin
set @out='Exam Name Already Exists.'  
end
end  

select * from tbl_exams
```

code:

```
public int InsertExamName(out string outMsg)
{
    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] p = new SqlParameter[5];
        p[0] = new SqlParameter("@ExamTypeId", Examtypeid);
        p[1] = new SqlParameter("@ExamName", Examname);
        p[2] = new SqlParameter("@Description", Desc);
        p[3] = new SqlParameter("@NoOfQues", Noofquestions);
        p[4] = new SqlParameter("@NegativeMarking", Negativemarking);
        p[4] = new SqlParameter("@Out", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150);
        p[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        int i = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Connection.con, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_InsertExams", p);//CHANGE STORE PROCEDURE NEGATIVE MARKING
        outMsg = p[4].Value.ToString();
        return i;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly format your question

Comment: If `Negativemarking` is null the parameter will not be added.  Check for null and use `DBNull.Value` instead.

Comment: Just a typo voting to close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You overwrite `NegativeMarking` SQlParameter by `Out` parameter instance. Must be:

```
    SqlParameter[] p = new SqlParameter[6];
    p[0] = new SqlParameter("@ExamTypeId", Examtypeid);
    p[1] = new SqlParameter("@ExamName", Examname);
    p[2] = new SqlParameter("@Description", Desc);
    p[3] = new SqlParameter("@NoOfQues", Noofquestions);
    p[4] = new SqlParameter("@NegativeMarking", Negativemarking);
    p[5] = new SqlParameter("@Out", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150);
    p[5].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```